# Currying Params, or, Component Factories in Svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have a simple Svelte component *<Greet />* which takes two params:

```html
<script lang=ts>
  export let greeting: string;
  export let name: string;
</script>

<strong>{greeting}, {name}!</strong>
```

How do I create a **function** which takes a single parameter, *name*, and returns a new component which takes one param, *greeting*, and renders *<Greet {greeting} {name} />*? Like so:

```html
<script lang=ts>
  import { greetFactory } from './greetFactory';

  const GreetMike = greetFactory('Mike');
</script>

<GreetMike greeting="Hello" />
// renders <Greet greeting="Hello" name="Mike" />
// which in turn renders <strong>Hello, Mike!</strong>
```

In other words: **How do I curry a param of a component?**

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [client-side component API](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api) to merge the props in. It would look something like this:

```js
  function greetFactory(name) {
        return function({ props, ...rest }) {
            return new Greet({
                props: {
                    name,
                    ...props,
                },
                ...rest
            });
        }
  }
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0866aacf9c63474b9af2dfa7fb929bec?version=3.48.0)

(If name is applied before the other props, it can even be overridden in the HTML.)